# Get json targeting data from facebook

Tags: html, json, facebook, post, get

Hi I want to get the users between 20-30 ages in some country for example island in json format from facebook in a get/post request.
is it possible?
instead of being arranged like this :
https://www.facebook.com/search/20/30/users-age

Comment: Yes. For that purpose facebook has its own api: [Graph Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/)

Comment: there is no api for this, and you would not be allowed to use the userdata in any way even if there would be an api. scraping the page is not allowed. in other words: it´s not possible.